# Nest js authorization where should i give user calss property of Roles

Tags: nestjs

in nest js Documentation i've read about Basic RBAC implementation but the last thing of this section says
"To make sure this example works, your User class must look as follows"

```
   class User {
  
  roles: Role[];
}
```

where should this line is going to be in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [authentication part of documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication). In [implementing passport strategies](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#implementing-passport-strategies) paragraph you have UsersService defined like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

// This should be a real class/interface representing a user entity
export type User = any;

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  private readonly users = [
    {
      userId: 1,
      username: 'john',
      password: 'changeme',
    },
    {
      userId: 2,
      username: 'maria',
      password: 'guess',
    },
  ];

  async findOne(username: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
    return this.users.find(user => user.username === username);
  }
}
```

You can create user.ts file near this service and import it here instead of defining type. How this class should look depends on source from which you get it. In this example users are hard-coded but usually that would be some kind of database entity.

### Hard-coded example

For this hard-coded example I would do User class like this:

user.ts

```
import { Role } from "./role.enum";
    
export class User {
  userId: number;
  username: string;
  password: string;
  roles: Role[];
}
```

Where roles are in enum defined in authorization part of documentation

role.enum.ts

```
export enum Role {
  User = 'user',
  Admin = 'admin',
}
```

All this is joined inside service like this:

users.service.ts

```
 import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
 import { User } from './user.entity';
 import { Role } from "./role.enum";


@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  private readonly users: User[] = [
    {
      userId: 1,
      username: 'john',
      password: 'changeme',
      roles: [Role.Admin]
    },
    {
      userId: 2,
      username: 'maria',
      password: 'guess',
      roles: [Role.User]
    },
  ];

  async findOne(username: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
    return this.users.find(user => user.username === username);
  }
}
```

### Database example

Usually you would use some kind of database (more on database integration [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database)), when using TypeOrm those classes would look like this:

user.entity.ts

```
import { Role } from "../role.enum";
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserEntity } from '../hard-coded/user';
import { InjectRepository } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { Repository } from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn() userId: number;
  @Column() username: string;
  @Column() password: string;
  // should have some kind of join table
  @ManyToMany() roles: Role[];
}
```

users.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(UserEntity) private usersRepository: Repository<UserEntity>){}

  async findOne(username: string): Promise<UserEntity | undefined> {
    return this.usersRepository.findOne({ username });
  }
}
```

Comment: should i create a table for roles and join it with many to many to user table or there is a best way to do it

Comment: Yes, I would use many to many with join table UserRole. You can try using '@ManyToMany' from nest to automatically generate join table or creating UserRole entity and joining by '@ManyToOne' by hand. You propably could use enum but your database would have to support enums or array columns. It is propably possible with Postgres but I would use join table solution - it is simple, easy to modify and works with every relational database.